# Clean URLs and passing parameters - best user experience

Tags: design-patterns, web, urls

I am passing parameters ("product category" & "product name") in a url to a buy page.

Which is preferable in regards to the norm/standard for passed parameters in Web URLs?

```
https://example.com/purchase/?productCat=personalSign&product=secureEmail
```

alternately:

```
https://example.com/purchase/?pcat=ps&p=se
```

i.e. Is giving full visibility of the parameters necessary? Or are shortcode random character strings acceptable in current Web design?

I would be very interested to hear advice on URL and parameter structure, with user/research data supporting any theories.

Comment: A website where users don't need to read/understand whatever parameters are in the url is already more user friendly than one where this matters. So ultimately, pick something that makes your job as a developer easier and let users ignore the url.

Answer (score 3):

Parameters in the URL make the URL not clean just by using them. I would rather go with URL structure like:

```
https://example.com/products/secureEmail/ - to show the details of a product
https://example.com/products/secureEmail/purchase/ - to start the procedure of buying
https://example.com/products/secureEmail/purchase/?step=2 - to navigate to another step of the buying procedure
```

The product page should know about its category.

Comment: And from a technical standpoint, most frameworks today will let you route the URIs to the right controller and grab these segments as variables.